# Entity Framework dbfirst создание таблицы

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

В проекте используется Entity Framework dbfirst, возникла ситуация когда необходимо ставить приложение множеству заказчиков, и соответственно будет множество БД. Если в БД у разработчиков была добавлена новая таблица и соответственно по ней была получена новая модель в коде (edmx), то есть ли способ средствами EF автоматически создать эту недостающую таблицу уже в базах заказчиков ? То есть суть вопроса в том, что при подходе dbfirst можно ли как-то создавать отсутствующие таблицы / поля на основании модели ?

Comment: У вас db first, но вы хотите при этом иметь code first? При подходе db first раньше делали специальный тип проекта в студии - проект бд, там в нем генерили нужные скрипты и запускали их при старте приложения. В вашем случае, вы также можете попробовать миграции (например миграции от ef или от fluent builder) но имейте ввиду, что судя по вашим требованиям, вам походу больше подходит code first подход.

Comment: Осмелюсь предложить пойти дальше. dbfirst и никакого entity framework, Только sql:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь миграциями https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli.
Сама база данных содержит информацию о миграциях, которые были применены, если вы будете поддерживать версионность миграций, то проблем не будет.

На практике: была миграция InitDB, которая была накачена на базу заказчика. Если появится у разработчиков новая миграция NewMigration1 и не была испорчена(переопределена) миграция InitDB, то все, что нужно сделать на базе заказчика - это выполнить команду update-database.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение, что некоторые миграции могут влиять на потерю данных. Ef при создании такой миграции уведомит об этом.